# Merge two arrays keeping the first array values as keys and second array values as values

Tags: php, arrays

Basically i have an array of key mappings (actually translations) and an array of data values. I want to essentially replace the keys of the second array with the values of the first array.

E.G.:

```
$array1 = array(
  'key1' => 'newkey1',
  'key2' => 'newkey2',
  'key3' => 'newkey3',
  'key4' => 'newkey4'
);

$array2 = array(
  'key1' => 'data1',
  'key2' => 'data2',
  'key3' => 'data3',
  'key4' => 'data4',
  'key5' => 'data5',
  'key6' => 'data6'
);

$result = array(
  'newkey1' => 'data1',
  'newkey2' => 'data2',
  'newkey3' => 'data3',
  'newkey4' => 'data4'
);
```

Edit: Added excess data to second array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're sure that the number of elements in both the arrays are same, you can simply use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$result = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

If your second array contains excess elements, then you could use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) to remove them before using `array_combine()`:

```
$values = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
$result = array_combine($array1, $values);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/131801)

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply. However as vee states what happens if the second array has some unwanted key/values?

Comment: @adamjg: Can you post an example array in http://eval.in ? I'm not sure what you mean.